# SceneKit Cylinder Physics strange behavior

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to create some kind of bowling pin, but after adding physics it just falls and then stand up again. Maybe it has to do with mass center, but I can't figure it out...

I've reduced code to a simple cylinder and a scene with an SCNFloor

```
func createPin(scene: SCNScene)
{
    let cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.04, height: 0.21)
    let sh1 = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: cylinder, options: nil)
    let cylinder2 = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.035, height: 0.21)
    let sh2 = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: cylinder2, options: nil)

    let sphereTransforms = [
        SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0.1,0)
        //SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0.1,0)
    ]
    let transforms = sphereTransforms.map {
        NSValue(SCNMatrix4: $0)
    }

    let demo = SCNNode()
    let node1 = SCNNode(geometry: cylinder)
    node1.transform=SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0.1,0)
    demo.addChildNode(node1)
    //let node2 = SCNNode(geometry: cylinder2)
    //node2.transform=SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0.3,0)
    //demo.addChildNode(node2)


    let shape3 = SCNPhysicsShape(shapes: [sh1], transforms: transforms)
    let body3 = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: shape3)
    demo.physicsBody=body3

    let trans=SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1,1,0.5)
    let rot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation((Float)(90*M_PI/180.0), 1, 0, 0)
    demo.transform=SCNMatrix4Mult(rot, trans)

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(demo)
}
```

Any guess?

Comment: That could a problem with the center of mass indeed. Did you try to not specify a specific physicsShape but let scene kit built a default one?

Comment: If I make that, the pin gets a shape that won't stand as the base is not a plane...